# How can I limit the amount of characters between a newline?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textarea that should only have 50 characters per line. I found a way to automatically add a newline after a user has typed 50 characters

```
$('#textarea').keyup(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length % 50 == 0 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\n');
   }
})
```

but this only just adds a newline after every 50 characters and doesn't really help. It also doesn't cover text that is pasted into the textarea. How can I simply prevent there from ever being more than 50 characters between every '\n' in the textarea? In other words, I want to have a fixed limit of 50 characters per line.

Comment: First of all, you really want to mess with what is being typed, or you just want this text to break line for displaying proposes?

Comment: Since you're silently inserting new lines, is there any reason you can't just do it server side? That way it won't matter how the text was entered (typed vs pasted).

Comment: @Havenard I want to actually mess with what is being typed.

Answer (score 0):

in your textarea have you set your cols to 50? it should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>autoresizing textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
border: 0 none white;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
outline: none;
background-color: #D0D0D0;
resize: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
observe = function (element, event, handler) {
    element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
};
 }
 else {
 observe = function (element, event, handler) {
    element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
 };
 }
function init () {
var text = document.getElementById('text');
function resize () {
    text.style.height = 'auto';
    text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
}
/* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
function delayedResize () {
    window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
}
observe(text, 'change',  resize);
observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

text.focus();
text.select();
resize();
}
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, cols doesn't do anything.

Comment: try the new script posted above

Comment: Cols just changes the width of the textarea for text-wrapping. I don't want any wrapped text, I just want a hard limit of characters between each newline

Comment: <textarea id="textarea" style="text-align:justify; text-wrap:none;" ></textarea>

Comment: can you do me a favor and post your full script? i can tinker with it for you

Comment: What I put above is all I have at the moment.